# Heroku timeout for simple calls to Postgres db

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, heroku

I created a simple Spring Boot application that is deployed on Heroku and uses a Heroku Postgres database. However, when I try to make a certain call to an endpoint, the call always times out (Heroku's 30 second timeout limit kicks in). I could increase the timeout limit, but this kind of call should just fire within seconds instead of timing out.

My application.properties. I included the last two lines to make sure I always have enough connections available to the database.

```
spring.datasource.url=<DATABASE_URL>
spring.datasource.username=<USERNAME>
spring.datasource.password=<PASSWORD>
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.database-platform=postgres
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle= 1
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size= 1
```

My controller. The method that fails is the getRandomPrizeByRank method.

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@RequestMapping("/")
public class PrizeController {
    PrizeService prizeService;

    public PrizeController(PrizeService prizeService) {
        this.prizeService = prizeService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/{rank}/prizes")
    public List<Prize> getAllPrizesByRank(@PathVariable String rank) {
        return prizeService.getAllPrizesByRank(rank);
    }

    @GetMapping("/prizes")
    public List<Prize> getAllPrizes() {
        return prizeService.getAllPrizes();
    }


    @GetMapping("/{rank}/randomPrize")
    public Prize getRandomPrizeByRank(@PathVariable String rank) {
        return prizeService.getRandomPrizeByRank(rank);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{prizeId}")
    public void removePrize(@PathVariable int prizeId) {
        prizeService.deletePrize(prizeId);
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/saveUsedPrize", consumes = "application/json")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void saveUsedPrize(@RequestBody UsedPrize usedPrize) {
        prizeService.saveRandomPrizeInUsedPrizeTable(usedPrize);
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/savePrize", consumes = "application/json")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void savePrize(@RequestBody Prize prize) {
        prizeService.savePrize(prize);
    }
}
```

My service, I'll limit this to the relevant methods for this call.

```
public Prize getRandomPrizeByRank(String rank) {
        List<Prize> prizeList = getAllPrizesByRank(rank);
        int randomPrizeId = prizeList.get(pickRandomPrizeFromListByRank(rank)).getId();
        return prizeRepository.findPrizeByRankAndId(rank, randomPrizeId);
    }

public List<Prize> getAllPrizesByRank(String rank) {
        return prizeRepository.findAllByRank(rank);
    }

public int pickRandomPrizeFromListByRank(String rank) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int randomPriceNumber = 0;
        int prizesLeftInRank = getAllPrizesByRank(rank).size();
        while (randomPriceNumber == 0) {
            randomPriceNumber = rnd.nextInt(prizesLeftInRank);
        }
        return randomPriceNumber;
    }
```

My repository:

```
public interface PrizeRepository extends JpaRepository<Prize, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT p FROM Prize p WHERE p.rank = :rank")
    List<Prize> findAllByRank(@Param("rank") String rank);

    @Query("SELECT p FROM Prize p WHERE p.rank = :rank AND p.id = :nextInt")
    Prize findPrizeByRankAndId(String rank, int nextInt);

    void deletePrizeById(int id);
}
```

I have no clue why this should timeout? I previously made similar simple apps and deployed them to Heroku and this always went smooth. This has been bugging me for days, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well it was pointing to a ridiculously stupid bug all along. Of course it was.

```
public int pickRandomPrizeFromListByRank(String rank) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int prizesLeftInRank = getAllPrizesByRank(rank).size();
        return rnd.nextInt(prizesLeftInRank);
    }
```

This fixed it. My test database didn't have enough elements inside of it, so the while loop you can see in the code in my question kept firing.